# Other options to using a mutex with my usage is very read heavy versus writes to shared state

Tags: rust

I have a web application using `axum` and I am currently storing my state like this:

```
 Arc::new(Mutex::new(MyState::new()))
```

I have some background tasks (spawns) that mutate this state, and I also reference this state from inside of my API endpoints.

I'm curious if there are other options to storing state.  In one situation, I have a 1000000:1 read to write ratio ie. 1 million reads to 1 write.

Is it possible to store state in a constant like way in memory, and then a background spawn calculates a new value, and then swaps it?
So in summary:

1. state referenced in my axum http api endpoints
2. background spawned task recalculates a new value, and swaps it once every hour

Just curious if there is another way since my situation is very read intensive with very infrequent writes.

Comment: have you considered using a broadcast channel?

Comment: I think [arc-swap](https://crates.io/crates/arc-swap) may be something that could help you.

Comment: At the very least, using an `RwLock` would allow concurrent read accesses.

Comment: @boreddad420 can you expand on that in an answer? not sure I follow